# PHP: Propel will save only first column

Tags: php, mysql, propel

I've been struggling with this problem for a while now and can't figure out reasonable explanation for this behaviour...

I have in MySQL a table called "notifications" and columns "package_id", "mail_sent_at" and "sms_sent_at", and appropriate Propel model for that. 
I'm setting "sms_sent_at" column with current time and saving it. Works perfectly.

```
    $not = new Notification();
    $not->setPackageId($package_id);
    $not->setSmsSendedAt(time())->save();
```

The result for this is:
[image]

Now I want to add one more thing - set mail_sent_at column. So what I do:

```
    $not = new Notification();
    $not->setPackageId($package_id1);
    $not->setMailSendedAt(time())->save();
    $not->setSmsSendedAt(time())->save();
```

And here's the magic: only mail_sent_at column was set.
 [image]

Additional notes:

1. after var_dump'ing i can see that dumped object has both properties set after executing these operations
2. var_dump'ing object retrieved from propel query by package_id after these operations executed doesn't have the second column set. As it is in DB.
3. Same behaviour happens other way around if I first set different column - first saved column goes into DB, second don't.

Why is that happening and how can I fix it?

Ps. Yeah, I know it's "sent", not "sended"

**EDIT**

**Finally I found the solution.** In case someone is having similar problem:
check if your primary key in propel schema has autoIncrement="true". If not - add it!
What was happening was: I've created a new object with id=null, saved it to DB using implicitly SQL INSERT (since it's new record ) and while working on the same object modified it and saved it to DB once again, but this time imlpicitly by SQL UPDATE (Propel figures out that I inserted this object once). The problem was, that after first saving I didn't get id for my object set (even though there was ID set in DB). So second SQL contained "UPDATE...WHERE id = NULL".

Comment: You're calling `save()` twice. You probably should call it only after `setSmsSendedAt()`?

Comment: Yes, I know. But this shouldn't be the case since I can call save wherever and whenever I want and Propel shouldn't make a problem about it.

Comment: What is the code behind the following methods in the `Notification` class?

- preSave
- preInsert
- save
- setSmsSendedAt
- setMailSendedAt

I would assume that there is some code in those methods (if they exist) that would clue us into what could be going on.